# Locus of image of point in a line.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

I am given the following question:

> Find the locus of the image of the point $(2,3)$ in the line
>
> $$\text{L}:(2x-3y+4)+k(x-2y+3)=0$$ where $k$ is any real number.

Attempt at solution.

I used a formula to arrive at (image of a point):

$\dfrac{x-2}{(2+k)}=\dfrac{y-3}{-(2k+3)}=\dfrac{2(1+k)}{(k+2)^2+(2k+3)^2}$

I know that it is a circle centred at $(1,2)$ with radius $\sqrt{2}$.

But I am having trouble solving the parametric equation. I need a quick way to do it or maybe to solve this problem in other way. It appeared in a recent National exam in India known as JEE - Mains 2015.

Addendum : Here's a graph https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5bweaiyj3a

Comment: I'm trying to create a site for "Indian Competitive Exams" and your question seems to be related to it, I think you would be interested to support it [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86609/indian-competitive-exams?referrer=uQtcXaMCGQOGlwjYmelKJA2) and spread the word to your friends?

Comment: I like your proposal but there are some limitations. Firstly the traffic is going to be a hell load of problem. Most of the people solve those problem for the sake of exam they don't wanna understand it they just want its solution for the sake of exam. And there will be less trafffic on this site as there are various sites for it

Comment: we can always modify the proposal

Comment: Another thing would be people won't accept the proposal if you are going to say ,like its for Indian exam only. It will become too biased. And certainly this is not the nicest place to discuss about it here in the comment section lol

Comment: let's get a chat room

Comment: here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23169/discussion-on-proposed-site-so-called-indian-competitive-exams

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The given line is actually a variable line (or you can say a family of lines) that pass through the intersection of the following two lines:
$$2x-3y+4=0 \qquad \text{ and } \qquad x-2y+3=0.$$
Their intersection point is $J=(1,2)$.

Let $P=(a,b)$ be the reflection of $Q=(2,3)$, then the mid-point $M=\left(\dfrac{a+2}{2}, \dfrac{b+3}{2}\right)$ of segment $PQ$ lies on the given line.

Now use a bit of geometric imagination to see that the lines $JM$ and $PQ$ will be perpendicular to each other (except in the degenerate case which happens when the variable line passes through the point $(2,3)$ itself). Thus  the slopes will follow:
$$m_{JM} \cdot m_{PQ}=-1$$
This is same as saying
$$\left(\frac{\frac{b+3}{2}-2}{\frac{a+2}{2}-1}\right).\left(\frac{b-3}{a-2}\right)=-1.$$
As you can see there is no parameter in this equation. Once you solve this you get:
$$a^2+b^2-2a-4b+3=0$$
which is same as 
$$(a-1)^2+(b-2)^2=2$$

Comment: Ah, I forgot about the common point of intersection , I actually tried that once but used a variable point, instead of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

After getting the point of intersection of the given family of lines we need to simply calculate the distance between the given point $(2,3)$ and the point of intersection of the family of lines i.e., $(1,2)$ which is equal to 
$$d=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$$
so $$d= \sqrt{(2-1)^2+(3-2)^2}=\sqrt2$$
Now by the definition of locus of a point (locus of a point at a distance d from a given point is a circle of radius $d$) we can say that the locus of the required point is a circle of radius $\sqrt2$

Comment: Actually , I got that much but still thanks. ^^